# NHibernate crashes IIS in easy query

Tags: nhibernate, heap-corruption

Very rarely, w3wp.exe crashes on the Production server and the analysis of the callstack points to NHibernate. The query is trivial.

This is the error I'm getting.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
>   System.AccessViolationException:Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt 
>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>   at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.FindValue(Expression expression) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionProcessor.cs:line 228
>   at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessSimpleExpression(Expression left, Expression right, ExpressionType nodeType) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionProcessor.cs:line 492
>   at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessOrExpression(BinaryExpression expression) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\ExpressionProcessor.cs:line 556
>   at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.Add(Expression`1 expression) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Criterion\QueryOver.cs:line 750
>   at Backend.DataAccess.AccountFeatureRepo.GetAccountFeatureByIdAndCode(Int32 accountId, AccountFeatureCode accountFeatureCode) in d:\builds\Backend.DataAccess\Repository\AccountFeatureRepo.cs:line 43

This is the code.

```
using (var session = GetSession())
{
    var result = session.QueryOver<AccountFeature>()
        .Where(af => af.AccountId == accountId)
        .And(af => af.FeatureCode == accountFeatureCode.ToString())
        .And(af => af.ActiveYN == "Y")
        .And(af => af.StartDatetime == null || af.StartDatetime < DateTime.UtcNow)
        .And(af => af.EndDatetime == null || af.EndDatetime >= DateTime.UtcNow)
        .OrderBy(af => af.Id).Desc
        .Take(1)
        .List();

    return (result != null && result.Count > 0) ? result[0] : null;
}

private static ISession GetSession()
{
    return SessionProvider.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
}
```

I can't reproduce the error and I can't think of anything wrong with the code. The arguments (account ID and feature code) are validated ahead of time so no garbage gets through here. I'm also afraid that with such a crash I'm looking at a heap corruption that originated somewhere else in the code and this part is all fine.

Thanks!
T

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the expression tree compilation on an element which is null, which you are then calling a method on or trying to evaluate it.

I see ProcessOrExpression in the stacktrace, so it might have something to do with your null check on the date. Try a Projections.SqlFunction("coalesce") on the date to SqlDateTime.MinValue for StartDate and SqlDateTime.MaxValue for EndDate.

I would also check to see if accountFeatureCode is null before calling ToString on it.